# Divergence in the second moment of a random variable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

As I ran simulations for my stochastic problem, I found that the variance $Var(X)$ is not convergent but the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is convergent. Here by "convergence" I mean the law of large number (LLN) holds so that
$$
\frac{\sum_{i}X_i}{n} \rightarrow \mu \text{ in prob}
$$
And by "divergence" I mean we cannot find such $\mu$.

Then I took a look into the second moment $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ which indeed is not convergent. But I am having difficulty to get an explanation for this.

So my question is what can we say about the divergence in the second moment of a random variable? Or is there any inequality I can reference to?

Comment: What is $X$ here?

Comment: $X$ is actually a random sum such that $X = \sum_{i=1}^{N}Y_i$ wherein $N = \inf\{n : Y_1 < C,..., Y_{n} < C, Y_{n+1} > C \text{ and } E(S_n) > P\}$ with $E(t)$ being the excess life of another stochastic process at time $t$ and $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_j$

Comment: $Y_j$'s are i.i.d exponential but $E$ is conditionally exponential

Answer (score 3):

Well, it can happen that $E|X|^p<\infty$ for some $p$ but not others, and you've met such a case.  You can often tell by looking at the density function or probability mass function of your rv.  If it decays like $1/|x|^{p+1}$ as $|x|\to\infty$ you can expect all moments less than $p$ to be finite and all greater than $p$ to not be finite, with a more delicate analysis deciding the borderline case.

It's unclear, though, precisely what you are asking.  Are you asking for hints in your problem set-up that might have given you an early warning of the possibility that $EX^2=\infty$ in your case?  Or for a general discussion of when moments converge and diverge?  The latter is contained in every modern probability theory book.  Look for the discussion of [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality).

Comment: In my case, the second moment $\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$ is divergent in the sense that $\mathbb{E}[X^{2}] < \infty$, but is bounded within a range $[a, b]$ not converging to some value. So in the figure generated from the simulation (500 replications) you can imagine it is highly jagged. And I wonder if there is any explanation both mathematically and economically?

Comment: Ah.  $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)$ exists but, as a function of $i$, has no limit but is restricted to a range $[a,b]$.  Well, that can happen too.  Interesting.